# SSIS oracle DB connectivity Issue

Tags: oracle, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, ssis-2012

I am getting the below mentioned error in one of the task in SSIS package.

---

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040
Error at Populate data combined data [OLE DB Destination [81]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step 
OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".

### Error at Task_Name [OLE DB Destination [81]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for Table_Name.Check that the object exists in the database.

I have Microsoft visual studio 2010 shell,  server management studio 2012 installed in my machine and also I have installed ODTwithODAC121012 and attunitySSISOraAdapters for the  DB connectivity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwpiP.png)
I tested the connection to the oracle DB and it is success.

Please let me know if there is something wrong with the connection setups.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can you login with SQLPlus and confirm that you have access to the table?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the table.

Comment: Are you able to query from Oracle DB ?

Comment: Can you possible add data flow diagram please, i guess u have to change delay validation property to True in Destination connection manager

Comment: @ Nick.McDermaid @B House.I changed the delay validation property to True , even then I am getting the error.

Comment: @Sukanya it could be validation error and unable to establish object connection , although DB connection is succeeded. I would add a new OLEDB destination and retest by disabling first one with a new connection manager

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid @B House. I tried creating new connection with new OLEDB destination, but throwing the same error. I noticed that in the OLEDB destination, data access mode is set as Table name or view name variable- fast load .
When the data access mode is changed to "Table name or view name variable" , then it's not throwing any error. Could you please help me to know what's wrong with the fast load?

Comment: Let me get this straight - you are _reading_ out of an oracle database and _loading into_ an oracle database, and the only issue you have is in the destination? Maybe the oracle driver just doesn't support "fastload" as SSIS defines it. If the source and target are on the same oracle server then it's quickest to just do a insert/select and not use SSIS

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid @B House Source is flat file(XL file) and destination is oracle DB. Is it the problem with Microsoft connector for oracle by attunity .

Comment: This https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b65408b3-68ee-445d-ad79-7812bcd8f5e0/failed-to-open-a-fastload-rowset?forum=sqlintegrationservices says that fast load can only be used with a SQL Server database... if it's true, then just use non fastload. Does it load fast enough?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : It's getting errored out when I use non fastload.Below mentione is the error.
Error: 0xC02020C4 at <task name>, Flat File Source [28]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
Error: 0xC0047038 at <task name>, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC02020C4

Comment: In a prior comment you said _When the data access mode is changed to "Table name or view name variable" , then it's not throwing any error_ is this the same thing?