# Fast Load Mode not working in SSIS Dataflow Task's OLEDB Destination (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am mirroring the tables from Sql server to Oracle. So its working absolutely find when I choose sql command as Data access mode. But I have millions of records in my table so wanted to switch Table or view -fast load access mode. As soon as I select fast load as data access mode it is showing me this error. Not able to click on mapping option and is throwing below error

Below is the error details TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040 Error at TABLE_NAME [OLE DB Destination [266]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
Error code: 0x80040E21. An OLE DB record is available.
Source: "OraOLEDB" Hresult: 0x80040E21
Description: "The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e21 in the message file for OraOLEDB.".
Error at TABLE_NAME [OLE DB Destination [266]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for ""USERSCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"".
Check that the object exists in the database.

Can somebody please advise here what needs to be done ??

Comment: what are the types of your fields?

Comment: Which fields are you talking  about source or destination or Data conversion in SSIS?

Comment: @MukeshTiwari Please check that your destination table is existed in Oracle. Error definition says It does't exist and can't send the records there.

Comment: Ozan Sen
It exists thats why I am able to load using Table or View Mode and SQL Query mode. How can the table not exists because of the fast load mode ??

Comment: try to have a look to a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338056/ssis-oracle-db-connectivity-issue

Answer (score 0):

Disable 64bit runtime in properties of project. It will work.